# How to write a proper HTTPS header?

Tags: node.js

I've built a NodeJS TCP server that sits on secured port 443.
Instead of sending HTTP snippets, I am using 443 to send my custom data through. 
It all works ok, until someone tries to navigate to the https address of node server.

Like to ask how do I send a 404 Not Found HTTPS response if someone were to navigate to the https address of my node server?

E.g:

```
if( isHTTPRequest ) {
  socket.write("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
  return;
}
```

Above doesn't work.

Comment: You'd need to do the full SSL handshake. Not sure if it's worth it.

Comment: Please don't even think about implementing `HTTPS` the fact you are asking this question proves that you don't know enough about security to even think about it. (I am not putting you down...very few people should think about implementing secure system).

Comment: Thanks guys! I guess I just return out.

Comment: You do realize that just being on port 443 doesn't intrinsically make anything secured, right?  If you're just using the `tcp` module to move data, you're almost certainly pushing plaintext across the wire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing magic about port 443; it doesn't intrinsically make things secure.  It's functionally the same as port 442, 444, 80, or any other.  The only thing that's special about 443 is that *by convention*, HTTPS servers listen on that port.

The thing that makes HTTPS servers secure is that they implement the [TLS protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).  TLS is a cryptographic protocol that provides an application a secure communication channel.  TLS provides the security; the server then runs regular HTTP on top of the TLS channel.

TLS isn't just limited to HTTP servers.  Any application can use it; its high-level APIs provide a data stream that works just like a regular TCP stream.

Fortunately, node [includes a complete TLS implementation](http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html) that is almost entirely API-compatible with a regular TCP stream provided by the `net` module.  So instead of:

```
net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.write('stuff that gets sent in the clear');
});
```

Do this:

```
tls.createServer({
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'), // the pem-encoded certificate
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'), // the private key that goes with your cert
    ca: [] // you may need to include the CA's intermediate certs if applicable
}, function(socket) {
    socket.write('stuff that will be encrypted');
});
```

Likewise, clients use [`tls.connect()`](http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_options_callback) instead of `net.connect()`.

You [generate](http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_ssl) your private key using OpenSSL, then submit a CSR to a [Certificate Authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority), who will give you a certificate that will be broadly accepted.  You can also self-sign, but self-signed certificates won't be accepted by clients by default.

Finally, given that you're writing a custom server (not a HTTP server), you shouldn't be listening on port 443.  Convention says that HTTPS servers listen on port 443, and your custom protocol isn't HTTP.  Select a different port, preferably one that [isn't already assigned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers).

Comment: Thanks Josh! My previous setup was a haproxy in front of a group of EC2 instances running NodeJS Net module. Haproxy was SSL enabled, so I presumed communications was "secured", even though I was running the Net module. Thanks a lot for the directions! Clearly I need to read a lot lot more. Reason why I thought of using 443 is because I thought I can bypass corporate firewalls easier.

Comment: Ok, if you have something like haproxy in front of your server that is actually doing SSL, then that's a different story. In AWS, it's OK if data between your load balancer and app server is unencrypted.  As far as corporate firewalls, yes, some do block connections that aren't 80 or 443.  However, some go as far as basically performing a MITM attack on HTTPS connections, so your non-HTTP protocol would end up getting blocked anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot Josh! Appreciate the long answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could let openssl client do the hard part.  Check out their documentation and examples.